# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in AVFoundation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation, fatal-error

I am making an application that uses flash light as a torch. I am writing the following code and XCode is giving me the error on the very first line. Can anyone please suggest the root cause of it? I am done debugging and can't seem to find it..

```
@IBAction func powerButton(sender: UIButton)
    {
        NSLog("flashButtonClicked")

        let flashLight : AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)!

        torchButton.setBackgroundImage(switchOnImage, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        NSLog("Button Background changed!!")

        if flashLight.torchAvailable && flashLight.isTorchModeSupported(AVCaptureTorchMode.On)
        {
            NSLog("inside if...")
            let success = flashLight.lockForConfiguration(nil)

            if (success)
            {
                if flashLight.torchActive
                {
                    flashLight.isTorchModeSupported(AVCaptureTorchMode.Off)
                    onOffbutton.setBackgroundImage(switchOffImage, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
                }
                else
                {
                    flashLight.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(100, error: nil)
                    onOffbutton.setBackgroundImage(switchOnImage, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
                }
                flashLight.unlockForConfiguration()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is it failing on? If you haven't already, you'll need to enable the all exceptions breakpoint in the break point navigator. Once you do that, the debugger should stop on the line where it's crashing.

Comment: Yes, i found out where it was failing, i already commented that below. I was running the code on a simulator. It was only through the hard way i got to know that Apple has no support for flash/camera/video in its simulator.

Answer (score 1):

`AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)` is returning a nil object. You're attempting to unwrap it (`!`) and assigning it to a non-nillable constant `let flashLight : AVCaptureDevice`

Try adding a check for nil

```
var flashLight = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
if flashLight != nil {
    //rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't sort it at all! I am using the function to turn on and off a falshlight. What good will that be if it didn't work? Can you please spot anything that i am missing here....

Comment: What devices are available? Try running this...

`var devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
        for device in devices {
            println(device)
    }`

Are you running this on the simulator? If you are, no AVCaptureDevices will be present

Comment: Yes, i am running this on a simulator. I didn't know Apple has left support for Camera/Video/Flash simulation...